# Update script domain from nokia.com to here.com

Tags: here-api

I have been asked to update the script domain from nokia.com to here.com, but the instruction wasn't that clear.

The current script is

```
https://api.maps.nokia.com/2.2.4/jsl.js
```

I have tried the following with no avail.

```
https://api.maps.here.com/2.2.4/jsl.js
https://api.here.com/2.2.4/jsl.js
```

What is the correct URL? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 2.x of the JS API is out of date (since at least a year, I believe). Even if you did switch to the latest URL you would run into issues because the API will try to call the old Nokia backends (see here: [Suddenly API crashes in routing-nlp.js, getting 503 Service Unavailable: Back-end server is at capacity back from call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38767942/suddenly-api-crashes-in-routing-nlp-js-getting-503-service-unavailable-back-en)).
You will have to migrate to JS API v3. This one is completely different from v2, so you won't be able to just switch out the script URLs. You may want to take a look at [developer.here.com](https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics/quick-start.html).